# One line Boolean check in Python

Tags: python, boolean, ternary-operator, idioms

I am a relatively newer Python developer, but I come from a Java background. In Java, there is one-line Boolean checker/assigner (for lack of a better term):

```
int result = (x)?y:z;
```

I am trying to use a similar approach in Python, but I am not sure whether this structure exists. Is there a way to declare a variable, check whether a condition is true and assign it to one of two values without using if/else?

Comment: OP, this has been asked on SO a billion times before.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
result = y if x else z
```

Comment: Man, I feel so stupid! Python is too intuitive for me :P